# "Clean" linking with dynamic libraries (no LD_LIBRARY_PATH)?

Tags: gcc, dynamic-linking, ldd

The title pretty much sums it up. I'm trying to link a dynamic library when compiling another. Here is my (short and humble) makefile:

```
all: src/
    gcc -fPIC -shared src/argsort.c -o libsort.so -lm
    gcc -fPIC -shared  src/kdtree.c -o  libkdtree.so -L./ -lsort -lm
```

So I'm first building libsort.so. It works great. Then I'm building libkdtree.so which uses libsort.so. The compilation goes great too, but libkdtree.so is unusable: here is the output of ldd for libkdtree.so:

```
ldd libkdtree.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcc54e000)
    libsort.so => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6b3c532000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6b3c172000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6b3ca57000)
```

If I add the directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it works, the link is there and I can use the library. Is LD_LIBRARY_PATH really meant to be changed like that ? Do I have no other choice ? I mean to share my code with others, and I'd like not to ask people to go add something to their .bashrc just so they can run my code. I think I don't understand what -L does, since I thought it would manually link the library.

Can someone either give me the magic method I overlooked, or crush my dreams of clean linking ?

Thank you !

Comment: Try -rpath linker option, though hardcoding library locations is a bad form.

Comment: Thank you for that, I will take a look at it, it seems to be doing what I want. However, I still don't understand what -L./ does if I need -rpath...

Comment: -L tells where to find libs at link time, -rpath thells where to look at run time.